# How can I change observation states' values in OpenAI gym's cartpole environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, open-ai, gym

I am learning with the OpenAI gym's cart pole environment.

I want to make the observation states discrete (with small stepsize) and for that purpose, I need to change two of the observations from [$
-\infty, \infty$] to some finite upper and lower limits. (By the way, these states are velocity and pole velocity at the tip).

How can I change these limits in the actual gym's environment?
Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend changing the rules of the environment.

What you could do:

Perform a method called bucketing i.e. take a value from a continuous state space see which discrete bucket it should go into and then let your agent use the bucket number as the observation.

e.g. Say I do have a continuous state space with one variable in range $[-\infty,\infty]$

The buckets can be as follows:

0). x < -1000

1). -1000 $\le$ x $<$ -500

2). -500 $\le$ x $<$ -100

3). -100 $\le$ x $<$ -50

4). -50 $\le$ x $<$ 0

5). 0 $\le$ x $<$ 50

6). 50 $\le$ x $<$ 100

7). 100 $\le$ x $<$ 500

8). 500 $\le$ x $<$ 1000

9). x > 1000

Therefore in this example scenario there are 9 buckets. Hence, the observations can be in range [0, 9] discretely.